# Not able to find photos on MBP

Tags: ios, objective-c

This code can't find photos from my Macbook pro (meta is nil). Trying to test this code on my MBP. The photos do exist in iPhoto. Is this code only works for iPhone/iPad? If yes, how do I test this code on my MBP?

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            if (asset){
                NSDictionary *meta = [[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata];
            }
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALAssetsLibrary` is [only available for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I assume you're running an iOS app in the simulator, is that right? iOS apps running in the simulator or a device can't access native Mac resources, due to the app sandboxing, and other similar reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Is there a way to test this functionality in my iOS app simulator? I want to make sure my app is able to access all photos  from iPhone/iPad.

Comment: Yes. You can add some photos to the photo library on the simulator, so your app can find them. One way to do it is to open a webpage in Safari on the simulator, and save an image from it (by long-pressing on it). Repeat until you have enough images :)

Comment: @codematrix If you want to be sure this finds all of the images in your iPhone/iPad then test the app on your iPhone and iPad.